# How to pass wildcard for XPath to be consumed by Selenium(c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to FindElements with XPath for my Selenium (C#) webdriver, which iterates through different account numbers in an angular rows. To know the number of rows present I want to get a count by passing wild-card for xpath, replacing the part where account number is passed. However, can't get this to work

Xpath are as below:

```
//*[@id="mr-name-1234568"]
//*[@id="mr-name-7895874"]
```

where AccountNumber = 1234568 & 7895874 (and might vary)

I have tried like below, but selenium isn't recognizing it -

```
var rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='mr-name-*']"));
int Rows = rows.Count();
```

It would be great to know how wild-card is passed above to get number of rows irrespective of what the account number may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **starts-with** in your OP case.

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
var rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id,'mr-name-')]"));
```

You have to use `starts-with` in this scenario as the first part of the `id` is consistent. Below is the general notation

```
 //tag[starts-with(@attribute,'first_static_part_in_attribute_value')]
```

***ends-with?*** *What to do if the dynamic content is at the beginning of the attribute value.*

`ends-with` is an option in xpath 2.0, but most of the common browsers like chrome, firefox support xpath 1.0. So we have to work around to achieve the outcome similar to ends-with using `string-length`,`substring` and `=`. Below is the example.

**Sample HTML:**

```html
<html>
   <body>
  <button id="mr-name-7895874">Dynamic content at the end 1</button>
  <button id="7895234-mr-name">Dynamic content at the start 1</button>
  <button id="104-mr-name">Dynamic content at the start 2</button>
  <button id="789523499-mr-name">Dynamic content at the start 3</button>
  <button id="mr-name-74">Dynamic content at the end 2</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now you have 3 buttons that are having dynamic number at the starting position, but the static text `-mr-name` is at the end. So we have to *find 3 buttons where id ends-with '-mr-name`*.

**Xpath 1.0: similar to ends-with in xpath 2.0**

```
//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('-mr-name') +1) = '-mr-name']
```

Let's see how this worked. Consider `104-mr-name` as id value for understanding purpose.

- string-length(@id) : This will find the length of the id attribute value (11 chars).
- string-length('-mr-name'): This will find the length of the string that we are checking for (8 chars).
- substring(@id,starting_position): Here the starting position is (11-8)+1= 4 (we are adding 1 to make sure we don't miss the first char `-`).
- Last step is compare both substring with the expected static string (here `-mr-name` is the static string) using `=`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thats working perfectly for me, thanks..!! but curious to know what would happen if the dynamic account number is at the beginning of that xpath?

Comment: Let me add the explanation to the answer itself for handling dynamic content at the beginning. So that you can better understand with example.

Comment: Check the updated answer, and let me know if you need any further information.